# Lattice points on $x+y=n$ always visible from the origin.

Tags: solution-verification, euclidean-geometry, coprime

Let $m \in \mathbb{Z_{\gt 0}}$ and $\{n \in \mathbb{Z_{\gt 0}}:n\mod 10\}$  = $\{1, 3, 7, 9\}$.

Define

$\Large a_{m} = \frac {5^m-3}2$

**Claim**

Any lattice points $(x,y)$ of the form

$\Large(\left \lfloor{\frac{n}2}\right \rfloor + a_{m} + 2,\left \lfloor{\frac{n}2}\right \rfloor - a_{m} - 1)$

where $x+y=n$ are always [visible](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/VisiblePoint.html) from the origin.

**Proof**

Let

\begin{align*}
x=\frac {n}2 + a_{m} + 2\\
y=\frac {n}2 - a_{m} - 1
\end{align*}

Point $(x,y)$ is coprime when

\begin{align*}
gcd(x,y)=1 \iff gcd(x+y,x-y)=1
\end{align*}

Calculating

\begin{align*}
gcd(x+y,x-y) &= gcd(n,\frac {n}2 + a_{m} + 2 - (\frac {n}2 - a_{m} - 1))\\
&=gcd(n,2a_{m} + 3)\\
&=gcd(n,5^m)\\
&=1\ or \ 5^m\\
\end{align*}

However, the only prime divisor of $5^m$ is $5$ and that is not a factor of $n$, so

\begin{align*}
gcd(x+y,x-y) &= 1\\
\end{align*}

Calculating

\begin{align*}
gcd(x, y) &= gcd(x−y, y),\ if\ (x > y)\\
&= gcd(\frac {n}2 + a_{m} + 2 - (\frac {n}2 - a_{m} - 1),\frac {n}2 - a_{m} - 1)\\
&=gcd(2a_{m} + 3,\frac {n}2 - a_{m} - 1)\\
&=gcd(5^m,\frac {n}2 - a_{m} - 1)\\
&=5^m\ or \ 1\\
\end{align*}

However, for any integers

\begin{align*}
\frac {gcd(x+y, x-y)}{gcd(x,y)}
\end{align*}

because anything that divides both $x$ and $y$ divides their sum and difference.

Substituting yields

\begin{align*}
\frac {1}{gcd(x,y)}
\end{align*}

Therefore

\begin{align*}
gcd(x,y) = 1
\end{align*}

$\blacksquare$

**Examples**

$\xrightarrow{\text{(n = 31, m = 1)}} (18, 13)$
$\xrightarrow{\text{(n = 31, m = 2)}} (28, 3)$

$\xrightarrow{\text{(n = 77777, m = 1)}} (38891, 38886)$
$\xrightarrow{\text{(n = 77777, m = 2)}} (38901, 38876)$

$\xrightarrow{\text{(n = 123456789, m = 10)}} (66611207, 56845582)$
$\xrightarrow{\text{(n = 123456789, m = 11)}} (86142457,37314332)$

$\xrightarrow{\text{(n = 9876543213, m = 12)}} (5060341919, 4816201294)$
$\xrightarrow{\text{(n = 9876543213, m = 13)}} (5548623169, 4327920044)$

**Note:** I only know basic high-school level maths.

Comment: HInt (I haven't tried). You ask lots of questions about whether points are visible from the origin. They are just when their coordinates are relatively prime. They will be relatively prime if and only if that is true for  their sum and their difference. I  would suggest you start there.

Comment: You said $x+y=n$ but the expression you wrote has $x+y=n+1$.

Comment: I assume $n/2$ for odd n means rounded down, then?

Comment: @Ian Yep, rounded down. Edited the question. (nothing easy). Thanks!

Comment: @EthanBolker Tried to actually prove it myself using your hints. Almost got it, I think? Thanks!

Comment: Ethan suggested you look at both the sum and the difference.

Comment: I get $x+y=n$ and $x-y=5^m$.

Comment: Is there some kind of relation between $gcd(x,y)=1 \iff gcd(x-y,x+y)=1$? In this case, $x-y$ and $x+y$  are coprime because $n$ isn't a multiple of 5 since it ends in $1,3,7,9$ only. Thanks!

Comment: As Ethan wrote, two integers are relatively prime if and only if their sum and difference are relatively prime. Well, not quite – if $x,y$ are both odd, and $\gcd(x,y)=1$, then $\gcd(x-y,x+y)=2$. That's the only exception. If $d$ divides both $x$ and $y$, then of course it divides both $x-y$ and $x+y$. If $d$ divides both $x-y$ and $x+y$, then it divides both $2x$ (their sum) and $2y$ (their difference), so it's either $2$ or it divides both $x-y$ and $x+y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overthinking this.

First, for any integers
$$
\gcd(x,y) \text{ divides } \gcd(x+y, x-y) 
$$
because anything that divides both $x$ and $y$ divides their sum and their difference.

In this question, $x -y$ = $5^m$. It's a little harder to see that $x+y = n$. (Since $n$ is odd, rounding down $n/2$ and doubling yields $n-1$).

The only prime divisor of $5^m$ is $5$ and $5$ is not a factor of $n$ so $\gcd(n, 5^m) = 1$.

Thus
$$
\gcd(x,y) \text{ divides } \gcd(n, 5^m) = 1
$$
so $x$ and $y$ are relatively prime.

(Note: be a little careful with odds and evens if you want to use this trick again. $\gcd(5,3) = 1$ but $\gcd(5-3,5+3) = 2$.)

Comment: Thanks! I'll study your solution in-depth, then re-edit my attempted proof. I wasn't aware of this handy tip: $\gcd(x,y) \text{ divides } \gcd(x+y, x-y)$